# KeyBoardAvoidingView not Doing anything

Tags: react-native, keyboard, keyboard-avoidance

I am using `<KeyboardAvoidingView/>` to try to create a messaging interface in React Native wherein upon entering the text field, the field raises up so the user can see what they're typing. I have the following syntax...

```
<Gradient
colorOne={COLORS.gradientColor1}
colorTwo={COLORS.gradientColor2}
style={{width: maxWidth * 1.00, height: '100%'}}
>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior="padding"
  enabled
  style={{flexGrow:1}}
  >
    {renderHeader()}
    {MainRender()}
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Gradient>
```

However, in execution, the following occurs...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try install `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` package and use it in your code like this:

```js
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView 
   enableAutomaticScroll={false}  
   bounces={false} 
   enableOnAndroid         
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
    {content}
 </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I was actually using this package before and it worked better but still not well. It created a weird gap between my keyboard and the page, and then I could scroll that gap to be bigger to the point where the whole screen was just my keyboard and a grey screen